# NuGet Package Manager

Tags: package, uwp-xaml

I can not install this with Package Manager Console:
Install-Package Microsoft.EnityFrameworkCore.Sqlite or Install-Package Microsoft.EnityFrameworkCore.Tools. It is returning:

Install-Package : Unable to find package 'Microsoft.EnityFrameworkCore.Sqlite'
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.EnityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Your Help will be so much helpfull. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you made a spell mistake on `entity` word (you are using enity). So it cannot find the right package. The right command should be

`Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite` not

`Install-Package Microsoft.EnityFrameworkCore.Sqlite`

Details please reference [UWP - New Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/uwp/getting-started). This article provides the correct command you can copy and use.

Additionally, EF Core requires Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform version 5.2.2 or greater. Please following the document for checking and upgrade.

Comment: When i was installing ENTITY  then i have this error. :(

Comment: Have you got any antoher idea ?

Comment: Or is here other way to install this package.. because i reaaly need it

Comment: ??     Please help me. Thank you mabn

Comment: Also if i follow instructions in UWP - New Database it does not work and it is returning this exception.. :(

Comment: What is your visual studio version and what is your .NetCore version and what is your OS version. Sorry for the late response but please comment with "@" character to me otherwise I will not see this. @theoodd.